# Using gMock for function call within function

Tags: c++, c, googletest, googlemock

I am unit testing a bit of code for coverage and am curious how I should handle this given situation.

I can't write the exact code here, so i'm using some placeholders.

```
TEST_F(testing, testingFunctionCall)
{
   bool result = FunctionCall();
   EXPECT_EQ(true, result);
}
```

Now the function call is in another file, and it requires another function to return a number for `FunctionCall()` to return true.

```
// In a seperate file
bool FunctionCall()
{
   int number = GettingNumberFromSystemState();
   if(number > A_CERTAIN_VALUE)
   {
      return  true;
   }else{
      return false;
   }
}
}
```

The function `GettingNumberFromSystemState()` will always return a false number because the firmware is not running on the hardware, so how would I create a mock function for `GettingNumberFromSystemState()` to always return the number I want?

Comment: Gmock is designed to define class methods in a mock class derived from your real class. Function `GettingNumberFromSystemState` looks like a C function. There might be other test frameworks better suited for C. You can create a wrapper function `GettingNumberFromSystemState` at file scope that will call a mock method in a mock object created by the constructor or `SetUp` function of the fixture class `testing`. Your test prog must link the mock function instead of the real one. Are `GettingNumberFromSystemState` and `FunctionCall` in different files? Is your source to be tested C or C++?

Comment: `GettingNumberFromSystemState` and `FunctionCall` are in different files, they are written in C, but all of the googletest files are in C++

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add all information there. It is possible to use googletest for C code, but it requires more work. Is there a specific reason to use googletest and not a framework designed for C? (see e.g. http://www.throwtheswitch.org/#download-section)